# suitable I/O model for the application which maintain 1000 TCP connection

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, winsock

I am working on Gateway Simulator which can simulate 1000 gateway.Gateway is connected with the data center and client app is connected with the data center.

Gateway

1. Stream the video to data center for playing or recording
2. Respond with status info about sensor connected with gateway
3. Other status information of the gateway to data center.

Data center
query the information from the client

Here gateway may at lenght having 1000 socket.I wanted to know the I/O.Gateway will run on both Windows and Linux developed using c++.Here i have restriction of not to use any third party library.

here how to manage so much connection in gateway.
1. receiving the request from data center which may be 1000 at max.
2. sending the response to data center.

I also need to I/O model required in windows and linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [C10K](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html) problem discusses this in great detail and should be enough to get you an understanding of what's involved in accepting a large number of connections.

Comment: Jeff your talking about third party library.I can't use them.this gateway is going to installed in embedded machine where memory size is limited....suggest something in  c++.

Comment: The page discusses various techniques on different OS's.  C++ doesn't have any networking libraries in the standard so you've got to base it on something (e.g sockets library).  What do you have available on your embedded machine?

Comment: I am planning to use overlapped I/O or completion port technique in windows machine there are APi for that in windows but same technique  or API is is not available in Linux .can we implement overlapped I/O or completion port in Linux using c++?

Comment: I think ePOLL/kQueue is the Linux equivalent (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67082/what-is-the-best-epoll-kqueue-select-equvalient-on-windows has more information though)

Comment: Jeff this just for my knowledge.Will boost asio will be  useful in this scenario.Since boost is supported in both and Linux.

Comment: I think so.  Looking at the overview page (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/implementation.html) it seems they abstract away the differences, but use overlapped IO on Windows / ePOLL on Linux

Comment: @Chris @Jeff Boost.Asio is the way to go here. The latest version is [1.46](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference.html).