# setTimeOut Equivalent in c?

Tags: c, sockets, pthreads

I am working on a pthread multi-threaded code and each thread is calling read() on a file descriptor. read() is a blocking call so it waits for data. But i want it to wait only for 3 secs to wait for data.

I thought of using alarm() and hadling SIGALRM but if I raise alarm in one thread, all the threads will got that SIGALRM signal and all of them will relinquish read. How can i do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`select`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/select.html) call for that. It has one argument that allows you to specify a timeout.

The Linux man page for [`select`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/select.2.html) has a sample usage, and you'll find lots of examples here and elsewhere on the web.

If you're not worried about portability, there are more modern/featureful options.

- For Linux, there's the [`epoll`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/epoll.7.html) facility. The man page has sample code, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27247/could-you-recommend-some-guides-about-epoll-on-linux) lists a couple of blogs with other usage information.
- For some of the *BSDs (and Mac OS X), there's [`kqueue`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=kqueue&sektion=2).
- Solaris has an [Event Completion Framework](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/event_completion.html)
- AIX has a [pollset](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-pollset/index.html) interface.
- For Windows, please see: [What is the best epoll/kqueue/select equvalient on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67082/what-is-the-best-epoll-kqueue-select-equvalient-on-windows)

You might want to look into libraries to abstract all that out. [libevent](http://libevent.org/) is worth a look, and wraps most of the above OS-specific interfaces.

Comment: select is deprecated. epoll is what people use these days.

Comment: oh yes, i think this should work. I never considered that use of select() before. I never considered select() for any other thing than multiplexing.

Comment: @VladLazarenko: "deprecated" is a bit of a strong wording for that. `epoll` isn't portable, and `select` isn't going away any time soon. Sure there are more modern alternatives, but they're also (IMO) often harder to get right.

Comment: @Mat: For a portable solution you are better off with some library like libevent, though it has a bunch of its own disadvantages. But yeah - it is not portable and not all of the features may be available on older kernels, like eventfd is not in Android yet. But frankly, epoll is a lot more powerful and IMHO easier to work with than any select/poll. I think epoll and kqueue are worth talking about here and not only mentioning select.

Comment: @VladLazarenko: feel free to post an answer then :)

Comment: @Mat: I am too lazy for that, so you get a +1 and I go to bed :)

Comment: @VladLazarenko: :) Since I'm just waking up, I added a few more references.