# Python, trying to get input from subprocess?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, subprocess

main.py

```
import subprocess,sys
process = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable]+['example.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
    out = process.stdout.read(1)
    if not out:
        out=process.stderr.read(1)
    if out == '' and process.poll() != None:
        break
    if out != '':
        print out
```

example.py

```
f=raw_input('WHats your favorite animal')
```

Ok I am wondering how I can check for input in my main loop and be able to give some data to it. Right now my program freezes when I use raw_input.

Here is what I would like

```
while True:
    out = process.stdout.read(1)
    if not out:
        out=process.stderr.read(1)
    if out == '' and process.poll() != None:
        break
    #showing what i want
    if request_input==True:
        give_input('cat') #Give input to the raw_input
    #
    if out != '':
        print out
```

I dont know if there is a feature like this. If you need more explanation please comment.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375427/non-blocking-read-on-a-subprocess-pipe-in-python

Comment: I am open to even using C++ stuff to get this to work. How does IDLE.py do it?

Answer (score 4):

This isn't really the best way to have interprocess communication, I recommend you either use the multiprocessing or threading libraries with something like either a Queue or PIPE for communication and synchronization.

a Queue would be simplest way for sharing data, one process would put in a value and another would get the values.

I've modified your original code so it works now, note that raw_input doesn't flush stdout as such if theres nothing there it will hang, http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-list/265749/ which is why your code was just waiting for stdout ...

**THIS IS DANGEROUS, it can generate deadlocks, use at your own risk, try another method.**

```
import sys
print 'Whats your favorite animal\n' #raw_input doesn't flush :( and we want to read in a whole line
sys.stdout.flush()
f = raw_input()
print f
```

and the corresponding main.py

```
import subprocess, sys, os
process = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable]+['example.py'],
     stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE, stdin = subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
    if process.poll() != None:
        break
    request_input = process.stdout.readline() # read line, this will wait until there's actually a line to read.
    if request_input == "Whats your favorite animal\n":
        print 'request: %s sending: %s' % (request_input, 'cat')
        process.stdin.write('cat\n')
       process.stdin.flush()
```

Comment: "request_input == "Whats your favorite animal\n":",  I am just looking for the general case when the raw_input function has been accessed.

Comment: I see thats a bit trickier since what raw_input usually does is just read from stdin calling readline on that file descriptor object, I was thinking of checking if that file has being opened but I think its opened automatically, as soon as execution starts :( sorry. multiprocessing/threading maybe the best unless you really need raw_input...

Comment: Ah i see, I am open to any solution,, What I am trying to make is a python IDE (for fun). Input in a ide is kinda important so I would need it. I guess ill just keep scouting for the answer, Again Thanks for replying

Comment: no problem, interesting, the best python IDE I've used is pycharm while not free, its great, you can take a look and maybe get some ideas :)

Comment: @user1357159 fundamentally is not possible wihtout modifying the python file since raw_input doesn't flush stdio, its a bug within python well 2.6 anyway, as such you can't get any outputs from the script

Comment: Is it possible using another version of python? I am open to any solution

Comment: @user1357159 Im going through the python source code, I'll let you.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**  Seems like I missunderstood your question, sorry about that.

This is not as easy as you might think:

You have to use `select` to check if there is data available in `stdin`, if there is data, read it!

Minimal example:

```
STDIN, STDOUT = 0, 1

while not process.poll() is None:
    out = process.stdout.read(1)

    if not out:
        break

    try:
        fds = select.select([STDIN], [], [])[0]
    except select.error:
        pass
    else:
        if STDIN in fds:
            data = os.read(STDIN, 1024)

            if data_requested:
                process.stdin.write(data)
```

Information to select: http://docs.python.org/library/select.html#module-select,   http://linux.die.net/man/2/select and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_(Unix)

Not sure if this will work on windows, since Windows just supports `select` on sockets. Relevant question on SO: [What is the best epoll/kqueue/select equvalient on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67082/what-is-the-best-epoll-kqueue-select-equvalient-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the multiprocessing module

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Value, Array

def f(n, a):
    n.value = 3.1415927
    for i in range(len(a)):
        a[i] = -a[i]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num = Value('d', 0.0)
    arr = Array('i', range(10))

    p = Process(target=f, args=(num, arr))
    p.start()
    p.join()

    print num.value
    print arr[:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you insist on "raw python", the best is to use pexpect module. I've added an output to your example.py, otherwise it is no fun at all.

Here is example.py:

```
    f=raw_input('WHats your favorite animal')
    print f.upper()
```

Here is pexpect-example.py you are looking for:

```
    # see http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html
    import pexpect

    PY_SCRIPT = 'example.py'

    child = pexpect.spawn('python %s' % PY_SCRIPT)

    child.expect ('WHats your favorite animal')

    # comment out these three lines if you run unmodified example.py script
    child.setecho(False)
    child.sendline ('cat')
    print PY_SCRIPT, 'said:', child.readline()
```

Comment: You don't need the print f.upper() call - abb was just adding that to display output to confirm the script worked.  The important part of the answer, the pexpect module, is almost certainly the most robust solution.

Comment: Sorry, i just skimmed through the answer. Ive looked into it and its nice but it only works on linux due to the modules that pexpect uses.

Comment: Also, Using "child.expect ('WHats your favorite animal')" will not work for me because I am looking for any raw_input case